# how to find the reason of failure on linux in case of jni call crash?

Tags: java, linux, debugging, crash, java-native-interface

on linux while runing my Java application involving JNI calls i notice few traces like below which looks like crash.

but the application continues and successful.

"A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: pure virtual method called"

What is the meaning of above trace? what could have made this failure? i do not get any core dump.
even if some time i get coredump, the failure stack is different each time. and nothing looks problematic in those calls.

any sggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any pure virtual functions, or if you are sure classes that do are purely abstract, that error usually indicate heap issues such as trying to call a method on a deleted object. Now with JNI, I would suspect GC issues. Try to run the code with a memory debugger to track down potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience: make sure you've killed previous Java before launching new one. And make sure the process IS dead (in my case this took a moment). Only then, launch a new one.

You may also want to add C/C++ tag to this, as this comes more from C side than it does from Java side. You may get more / better answers. In my case this came with a GC warning, but I haven't yet investigated this.

A good read:

1. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PureVirtualFunctionCalled
2. http://tombarta.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/gcc-pure-virtual-method-called/

Two quotes from these places, as I know some folks want their answer all in one place.

C2 Wiki:

> The reason, by the way, is that a child virtual may access instance
>   members that may not have been constructed or already have been
>   destroyed. Thus, you cannot call a child virtual.

Tombarta's blog:

> Why was this happening? Because I was **deleting objects while they were still in use**.